# InterpolatingPolynomial: magnitude of coeffictions

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a list of the type {{x,y},f} and want to get an `InterpolatingPolynomial` for that list. The x values all run between 1.3 and 2, the y values between 0 and 1. The function values all lie in the range 0 to 1.2:

```
A = {{{1.35, 0.273984}, 0.728733}, {{1.375, 0.257642}, 
0.818659}, {{1.4, 0.242488}, 0.92725}, {{1.425, 0.228405}, 
1.02997}, {{1.45, 0.215288}, 1.12053}, {{1.475, 0.203047}, 
1.24364}, {{1.5, 0.191601}, 0.991427}, {{1.525, 0.180881}, 
0.591806}, {{1.55, 0.170822}, 0.536831}, {{1.575, 0.16137}, 
0.626643}, {{1.6, 0.152475}, 0.593617}, {{1.625, 0.144091}, 
0.515524}, {{1.65, 0.136179}, 0.45724}, {{1.675, 0.128702}, 
0.478962}, {{1.7, 0.121628}, 0.582782}, {{1.725, 0.114927}, 
0.537581}, {{1.75, 0.108572}, 0.533521}, {{1.775, 0.10254}, 
0.524312}, {{1.8, 0.0968073}, 0.519375}, {{1.825, 0.0913544}, 
0.495156}, {{1.85, 0.0861626}, 0.466659}, {{1.875, 0.0812149}, 
0.426044}, {{1.9, 0.0764957}, 0.387338}, {{1.35, 0.344327}, 
0.391499}, {{1.375, 0.324598}, 0.681933}, {{1.4, 0.306041}, 
0.835192}, {{1.425, 0.288563}, 0.962204}, {{1.45, 0.272079}, 
1.12803}, {{1.475, 0.256515}, 1.02705}, {{1.5, 0.241801}, 
0.985249}, {{1.525, 0.227875}, 0.488567}, {{1.55, 0.214682}, 
0.456916}, {{1.575, 0.202169}, 0.406596}, {{1.6, 0.190289}, 
0.40218}, {{1.625, 0.179001}, 0.322154}, {{1.65, 0.168264}, 
0.307378}, {{1.675, 0.158042}, 0.375889}, {{1.7, 0.148304}, 
0.436761}, {{1.725, 0.139017}, 0.460715}, {{1.75, 0.130155}, 
0.459744}, {{1.775, 0.121691}, 0.415649}, {{1.8, 0.113601}, 
0.372864}, {{1.825, 0.105864}, 0.332083}, {{1.85, 0.0984584}, 
0.307228}, {{1.875, 0.091366}, 0.282702}, {{1.9, 0.0845688}, 
0.282029}, {{1.925, 0.0780506}, 0.283576}, {{1.95, 0.0717961}, 
0.245998}, {{1.35, 0.522927}, 1.21534}, {{1.375, 0.49884}, 
1.23622}, {{1.4, 0.475296}, 1.21129}, {{1.425, 0.452287}, 
1.17794}, {{1.45, 0.429808}, 1.14154}, {{1.475, 0.407849}, 
1.05781}, {{1.5, 0.386401}, 0.735886}, {{1.525, 0.365456}, 
0.20484}, {{1.55, 0.345005}, 0.169725}, {{1.575, 0.325039}, 
0.29341}, {{1.6, 0.305547}, 0.33619}, {{1.625, 0.286519}, 
0.290241}, {{1.65, 0.267947}, 0.234699}, {{1.675, 0.24982}, 
0.259155}, {{1.7, 0.232129}, 0.425316}, {{1.35, 0.768514}, 
0.803047}, {{1.375, 0.75328}, 0.856855}, {{1.4, 0.737953}, 
0.896618}, {{1.425, 0.722541}, 0.937661}, {{1.45, 0.707051}, 
0.894388}, {{1.475, 0.691488}, 0.918156}, {{1.5, 0.675859}, 
0.782395}, {{1.525, 0.66017}, 0.253692}, {{1.55, 0.644428}, 
0.300553}, {{1.575, 0.628638}, 0.544507}, {{1.6, 0.612806}, 
0.707503}, {{1.625, 0.596938}, 0.802465}, {{1.65, 0.58104}, 
0.871258}, {{1.675, 0.565117}, 0.941302}, {{1.7, 0.549175}, 
0.984023}, {{1.725, 0.533218}, 0.895298}, {{1.75, 0.517252}, 
0.856245}, {{1.775, 0.501282}, 0.871947}, {{1.8, 0.485312}, 
0.893617}, {{1.825, 0.469347}, 0.91226}, {{1.85, 0.453392}, 
0.923564}, {{1.875, 0.437452}, 0.92351}, {{1.9, 0.42153}, 
0.908258}, {{1.925, 0.40563}, 0.878031}, {{1.95, 0.389758}, 
0.838854}, {{1.975, 0.373915}, 0.798399}, {{2., 0.358107}, 
0.761601}, {{1.35, 0.780351}, 0.155121}, {{1.375, 0.766322}, 
0.389603}, {{1.4, 0.75226}, 
0.397601}, {{1.425, 0.738171}, -0.0631589}, {{1.45, 
0.724062}, -0.358085}, {{1.475, 0.709939}, -0.0143939}, {{1.5, 
0.695809}, 0.42667}, {{1.525, 0.681677}, 
0.53292}, {{1.55, 0.66755}, 0.627926}, {{1.575, 0.653433}, 
0.671135}, {{1.6, 0.639331}, 0.563348}, {{1.625, 0.625249}, 
0.44906}, {{1.65, 0.611193}, 0.371806}, {{1.675, 0.597168}, 
0.576316}, {{1.7, 0.583177}, 0.957115}, {{1.725, 0.569226}, 
1.13763}, {{1.75, 0.555318}, 1.07013}, {{1.775, 0.541459}, 
0.993664}, {{1.8, 0.527651}, 0.945529}, {{1.825, 0.513899}, 
0.923353}, {{1.85, 0.500206}, 0.951844}, {{1.875, 0.486575}, 
0.941281}, {{1.9, 0.47301}, 0.938516}, {{1.925, 0.459513}, 
0.917569}}
```

When I apply `InterpolatingPolynomial` to that list

```
test = InterpolatingPolynomial[A,{x,y}]
```

I get a polynomial with very large expansion coefficients of the order `10^8` to `10^13`. This is undesirable. How can I avoid this behavior? Further: if I then try to check the interpolating polynomial by simply doing`test[1.4,0.5]`  I am just getting the polynomial again, but no value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "This is undesirable." - but expected, all the more since you have equispaced $x$-coordinates.

Comment: Would `Interpolation` serve your purpose?  — For the secondary question `test /. {x -> 1.4, y -> 0.5}` or  defining `test` as a function `Clear[test]; test[x_, y_] = ...; test[1.4, 0.5]` would evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: @Michael E2: I now define the function by saying
    test[x_,y_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[A,{x,y}]
and then 
    test[1.4,0,5] 
gives a completely wrong value : -5.6*10^8. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like evaluating your polynomial (at least in this fashion) is just numerically unstable. Why does it have to be a polynomial as opposed to e.g. a piecewise polynomial?

Comment: Your surface is not very smooth, therefore you need high order polynomials, what leads to cancellation and therefore numerical instability. Furthermore, high order polynomials tend to oscillate between data points and should be avoided. As already mentioned, do you really need polynomials?  Do you need to reproduce your surface accurately? Or could you smooth your surface?

Comment: @DanielHuber : Thanks for your helpful comments. No, I do not need to reproduce the surface accurately. And, yes, smoothing the surface would be very helpful. How do I do that smoothing best?

Comment: Many different possibilities. E.g. MedianFilter or  MeanFilter or MovingAverage or MovingMedian or ExponentialMovingAverage or GaussianFilter ....

Comment: thanks for these hints. I am not a Mathematica expert: is there a premade routine that allows to directly apply one of these filters to the given example? I tried movingAverage, but that also averages the (x,y) values. I, however, need to keep the original net and just smoothen the function values f.

Comment: to smoothen the function values I need to average the function value at each point (x,y) over the values at the neighboring points in both dimensions.